# How to delete duplicate column names when merge datasets by one column name in R?

Tags: r

## Merge two datasets by one column name:

mergeAll <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="houseID")

This code will keep all the variables in the two datasets, if there are duplicate variable names such as, dataset1 and dataset2 both have "ID", the mergeAll will have ID.x (for ID in dataset1), and ID.y (for ID in dataset2).  How to delete duplicate variable names? We only want to keep one ID as they are the same in both dataset? Or, if their values are not the same, we only want to keep the ID variable in the first dataset (i.e. dataset1).

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete it  (e.g. ID.x) and rename "ID.y" to something more meaningful e.g. "ID":

```
require(dplyr)
mergeAll <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="houseID") %>%
                  select(-ID.x) %>% 
                  rename(c("ID"="ID.y"))
```

Comment: Do we have a better way? The dataset might be large and might have lots of duplicate variables such as ID1, ID2, ... IDn, lots of work if we delete and rename them, as we have to identify them first. It might be hard.